# leading digit in css class name = not working

Tags: css

I was struggling with an image styling:

```
<img class="2logos" src="logos.png" />

.2logos {width: 166px}
```

Whatever I tried, it did nothing. Until I removed the digit from the class name. As soon as I named it "logos" instead of "2logos", it worked. I never noted something like this before. Where may the restriction come from? I find this very strange!

Comment: Here's the spec on using numbers in CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Answer (score 2):

When you reference a class name in a CSS selector, you need  to remember that if a first character is not a letter, underscore or a hyphen, you need to escape it.

(You can use [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) to verify your stylesheet.)

To escape first digit in your class name, use a `\3x`notation (which is short for a full `\00003x` you'd use for digits in Unicode):

```
.\32 logos { ... }
```

[(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/xm0zmg4q/1/).

[Here's a good article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) on escaping in CSS.

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. However, a leading digit needs to be escaped when writing the CSS selector.

Comment: True, I expressed this in a worst possible way @torazaburo :/

Comment: Actually it needs to be `\32(space)logos`.

Comment: Right. Thought the non-spaced version worked for me in Chrome as well.

Comment: Thank you. I really was not aware of that. It feels so strange: I do webdesign (as a designer, not a programmer though) for so many years now, but I really never came across this problem until now!

Comment: @thomhawk To be honest I didn't know precisely how to handle it either. I just recalled seeing it somewhere, so I looked it up (well, class name with a leading digit is a little unorthodox ;)). That's what I like about SO, I keep learning by providing answers!